# Reflexive pronoun with another object/multiple objects

Tags: verbos, reflexivos, objetos-directos

If I want to say "I wash myself and you," how is that said?  "Se y te lavo?"  Or "se lavo a mi y ti?"  I haven't been able to find any information on this topic; most of what I've found is two objects but one indirect and one direct. (e.g. "Se lo leo a él")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot coordinate (*A y B*) object pronouns.

You really only have two options:

- conflate the pronouns and adjust the verb: *nos lavamos*
- restate in full: *me lavo a mí y te lavo a ti también*

Here is what the *Nueva Gramática* (RAE) has to say about it (an asterisk in front of an example means it is considered ungrammatical):

> **16.4g** […] La concordancia de los reflexviso con su antecedente no puede ser **parcial**.  El reflexivo y su antecedente no pueden, en consecuencia, compartir solo algunos de sus rasgos morfológicos.  Por esta razón la lengua rechaza oraciones como **Yo nos compré ayer los billetes* o **Nos he preparado un postre especial*.  Estas oraciones anómalas expresan significados comprensibles, ya que es natural preparar un postre o comprar los billetes para uno mismo a la vez que para los demás.  Su irregularidad radica en que no se da en ellas la concordancia de número entre el reflexivo y su antecedente, sino solo la de persona: *Yo* [1.ª persona **singular**] *nos* [1ª persona **plural**] *compré ayer los billetes*.  Un razonamiento similar excluye secuencias como **Os das la enhorabuena* (cf. *darte los demás la enhorabuena y también tu a ti mismo*) o **Me traemos suerte*.
>
> **16.4h** La construcción sobre la reflexividad parcial deja de ser efectiva cuando los elementos que se comparan no son argumentos o adjuntos del mismo predicado (recuérdese que *yo* y *me* son dos argumentos de *afeitar* en *Yo me afeito*). Este mismo criterio pone de manifiesto, en opinión de algunos gramáticos, que, cuando se pierde esa relación de coargumentalidad, se pierde también la de reflexividad en sentido estricto.  Contrastan muy claramente, en efecto, **Nos compré los billetes* con *Compré los billetes para nosotros*, aun cuando ambas oraciones expresarían significados muy próximos.  El sujeto y el pronombre *nos* son complementes del mismo verbo (*compré*) en la primera de estas dos oraciones.  En la segunda, por el contrario, el pronombre *nosotros* no es complemento de *compré*, sino término de la preposición *para*.  No es, pues, forzoso que establezca una relación de reflexividad con el sujeto de dicho verbo.  El que la restricción que impide la concordancia parcial tienda a darse entre elementos que ejercen funciones paralelas respecto de un mismo predicado se ve también confirmado por el hecho de que no sean incorrectas ni agramaticales oraciones como *Nos veo a todos desocupados* (o *en el paro*) *dentro de poco*.  El pronombre nos es el complemento directo de *veo*, pero es a la vez el elemento del que se predica desocupados.

The oddness of the last bit might make a bit more sense after reading §16.4u (omited here for brevity)

As noted in the comments, the construction *nos lavamos* might seem to imply that either (a) each person was washing themself or (b) each person was reciprocating the washing to each other person.  However, as noted in the *Nueva Gramática*:

> **16.5r** […] Se ha observado, sin embargo, que la reciprocidad no se da siempre de forma estricta en términos semánticos, sin que ello lleve a pensar que los pronombres que establecen esas relaciones dejen de ser recíprocos.  Ciertamente, si sabemos que Manuel no detesta a Jaime, la oración *Manuel, Jaime y Carlos se detestan* no describirá una situación verdadera.  Repárese ahora en que el significado de la oración *Las hojas de los árboles se tocaban* no puede ser el que corresponde a ‘Cada hoja de cada ábrol tocaba alas demás y era tocada por estas’, puesto que es prácticamente imposible encontrar en el mundo real una situación como la que se describe.  Las relaciones de reciprocidad que se aplican a los conjuntos de personas o cosas son a menudo **no estrictas**, en el sentido de que no debe esperarse que cada elemento de un conjunto ejerza sobre todos los demás la acción que el verbo describe, y que a su vez la reciba de acada uno de los otros elementos de ese grupo.

Comment: I can't find any example online, and NGrams fails me, but *maybe* (doubtfully) you could say *nos lavamos yo a nosotros*. With non reflexives, you can use *para*: *doy algo para nosotros*, but that sounds very odd with *lavar* to me, but maybe not (doubtful) to everyone: *lavo para nosotros*

Comment: (I included the two as comments because I doubt their actual possibility and want to leave my answer with things that are for sure)

Comment: I see you left «nos lavo» out, but I cannot see anything ungrammatical with that, and I find it would be more accurate. In fact «nos lavamos» is betraying the original meaning, as there's only one person holding the sponge in OP's question.

Comment: @guillem you can't say *nos lavo* per DPD's entry *pronombres personales átonos.7b.*: No puede haber correferencia parcial entre el clítico y el sujeto del verbo; por ello no es posible una oración como *Nos hice una cena riquísima (el referente «yo» del sujeto es solo una parte del referente «nosotros» del complemento indirecto). Los referentes han de ser, o bien totalmente distintos, o bien totalmente coincidentes: Os hice una cena riquísima (sujeto «yo» y complemento indirecto «vosotros»);Nos hicimos una cena riquísima (el referente del sujeto y del complemento indirecto es «nosotros»).

Comment: So can't you say «nos veo reflejados en el espejo»? OP's question and my examples are different from yours (which implies an I.O.), does that norm apply too? Sorry for not checking myself but roday I'm mobile and roaming.

Comment: @guillem : no, I'm going to update here with the information from the *Gramática*.

Answer (score -1):

> I wash myself and you = Yo me lavo y te lavo

or

> Yo me lavo a mi mismo y te lavo a ti

`Yo nos lavo` could be grammatically correct but sounds weird even if `Yo nos veo en el espejo` sounds ok.